# Move child elements smoothly in resizing div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a header which becomes about a fourth of the original size when scrolling down, which creates a need to move the elements inside of it. Right now, I'm just setting margins on the children elements, in order to position them correctly in the new sized div. This created a good structure after resizing the div, but it doesn't look good while the changes are happening as they just instantly snap to the new positions, as I don't have any animations going.

So I'm wondering -- how can I make a smoother transition when moving an element from point A to point B?

Relevant CSS from header div:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

and the children are just basic elements, with `display: block` and some margins to position them correctly.

Is there something I can do in action, to make the transition smoother? I looked at `.animate()` but it seems to work with absolutely positioned elements which are not the case for me.

Comment: Have a look a setting a css transition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Can you upload a example on jsfidle?

Answer (score 0):

You can `.animate()` elements in **jQuery** with not only absolute position, but with fixed and relative as well.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srckv0mv/1/) with relative position for example.

If you still don't want to use `.animate()` comment below.